# C++ Meaning of an extra pair of parentheses after parameter list in a function definition

Tags: c++

In section 2.3 of the book "*C++ Templates - The Complete Guide (2nd Edition)*", the authors present the following code snippet:

```
template<typename T>
class Stack {
  ...
  void printOn() (std::ostream& strm) const {
    ...
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& strm, Stack<T> const& s) {
    s.printOn(strm);
    return strm;
  }
};
```

I'm a little confussed about the meaning of the second pair of parentheses before the *const* specifier. I've never seen that syntax before; and after looking for a while on the internet and in other books I have, I couldn't find an explanation.

I don't think it is a typo: the same code is repeated in another part of the book, and it is not mentioned in the errata of the book.

What is this called? What is its purpose?

Thanks in advance

---

**Update:** As @chris pointed out, it was a typo, and it does figure in the errata. Somehow, I didn't see it. Thank you all, and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Is that a part of a larger snippet?

Comment: It is, but I didn't think it added something important to the question. Since it  probably does, I just copied the whole snippet.

Comment: That's broken. It's declaring a function taking no arguments returning a function type `void (std::ostream&) const`. That dog doesn't hunt .

Comment: See [the errata](http://www.tmplbook.com/).

Comment: @WhozCraig - quibble, *"doesn't"*, *"won't"* -- must be a regional thing...

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you copy pasted this from a larger block of code (due to it looking like a template function with extra undeclared variables).

That said, it still doesn't look like standard syntax. I tried compiling it, but it yields this error:

```
error: 'printOn' declared as function returning a function
```

However, functions shall not have a function as a return type, as explicitly stated in the [dcl.fct](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct) standard:

> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function

Do note though, that this kind of syntax **can** appear when overloading `operator()` like this:

```
MyClass operator()(int a, int b, int c) {
     MyClass M;
     M.sum = a + b + c;
     return M;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As chris pointed out, it was a typo, and I didn't see it in the errata.